# Inflating custom RowView override ListView click events?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm running into an issue after inflating my custom `RowView` into my `ListAdapter` that I've bound to my `ListView`. I have a `ItemClick` event registered on my `ListView` item and when it is clicked, I expect the `DetailView` to be opened. However, it appears my click event is being overwritten as nothing happens when I click on the `ListView` item.

Here is a sample of the `ExplorerActivity` class that uses the `ListView`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ExplorerView);

        exampleListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.exampleListView);

        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
                                 "TestDb.db3");

        SQLiteConnection myConn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);                

        allItems = dbHelper.GetAllItems();

        exampleListView.Adapter = new exampleListAdapter(this, allItems);

        exampleListView.ItemClick += exampleListView_ItemClick;
}
```

Sample `ListAdapter` code:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var item = items[position];

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomRowView, null);
    }

    convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ItemTextView).Text = item.Name;

}
```

If I inflate a custom `RowView`, do I lose the click events I've registered on the `ListView` items? I've not been able to add the event to the entire custom`RowView` in the `ListAdapter`, so I assumed it would be a `ListView.ItemClick` event.

Are my click events on the `ListView` being disregarded by the custom `RowView`? Each instance of a `RowView` is still a `ListView` item, correct?

I can't seem to find the proper object, e.g. `RowView` isn't a thing, so how do I bind an event the the `ListView` item after being inflating my custom `RowView`?

I've tried setting breakpoints in the explorer activity, but they are never hit, which is why I think the event no longer is registered on the `ListView_ItemClick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I inflate a custom RowView, do I lose the click events I've registered on the ListView items?

No, you won't lose the item click event of `ListView`. Item click event should be triggered correctly.

> Are my click events on the ListView being disregarded by the custom RowView? Each instance of a RowView is still a ListView item, correct?

I made a basic demo for test, the Item click event can be triggered correctly. You can try my demo [here](https://github.com/elvisxia/ListViewDemo)

> I can't seem to find the proper object, e.g. RowView isn't a thing, so how do I bind an event the the ListView item after being inflating my custom RowView?

One way is to bind the Item Click event of `ListView`. Other way is to bind click event to the inflated view:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var item = mList[position];

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = mContext.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomRowView,null);
    }
    var btn = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.mBtn);
    btn.Click += Btn_Click;
    return convertView;
}

private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do your job here
}
```

**Updates:**

The issue lies on the buttons, once the buttons are added to the row view, the `ItemClick` doesn't work. If you want the `ItemClick` to work, you need to add `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to every button like below:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="Click Me"/>
```

Comment: I will walk through your example this evening and respond with any questions. Thank you!

Comment: I downloaded your demo and walked through the code. You code works as I expect, mine does not. No click events are registered. Here is my project: https://github.com/jmbarnes1987/Namely if you would please take a look at my project and let me know what I'm doing wrong, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Is it possible all the other controls I add to the RowView, e.g. image, textviews, buttons, etc, are making it impossible to actually click the row? The problem with that theory is I can click the text in your example and it still works.

Comment: You need to set the buttons unfocusable, please check my updates in the answer.